# Where do Chrome, Chromium and Firefox store offline data

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium

As the question says, where do each of the browsers store their offline data, be it cache, offline storage from html5, images, flash videos or anything web related that gets stored locally.

Comment: check ~/.config/google-chrome

Comment: The chrome one was tough since it has one part in .cache/google-chrome and the offline storage in the folder you mentioned. Thanks Eng.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firefox store the offline data in `~/.mozilla` directory, to be more specific in `~/.mozilla/profiles/xxxxxxxx.default` directory.

Chrome uses `~/.cache/google-chrome` directory for storing cache. Google chrome also uses `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` directory for storing recent history, tabs and other things.

Like Chrome, Chromium uses as such with only the name changed. That is  `~/.cache/chromium` and `~/.config/chromium/Default`

Comment: nice answer, can you add this to it: .config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage for the local storage.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Done

Comment: I found some Chromium files in `/etc/chromium`. I believe they are related to LastPass.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I found the Chrome stored its cache files into  these places, but you can't export them, because they are in a kind of secret format. How can we export and list those files?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found that the flatpak chromium uses

```
~/.var/app/org.chromium.Chromium/cache
```

On Firefox I use the browser.cache.disk.parent_directory "preference" in about:config to get it to use somewhere that's not backed up, to reduce backup sizes.